# Having trouble in Datasource for Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid, sqldatasource

I am a bit stuck with codes and need your help.

Since my RadGrid holds RadAsyncUpload to save the file in file system therefore I have to configure my datasource in codes :(   ... or you can say this is the only way i know how to make it work.

I am stuck with Select command with "WHERE" .. can anyone guide me how to mention the select parameter please.

here are my codes;

```
public static string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BaseConn"].ConnectionString;
    }
}


protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    string PhoneID = RadComboBox1.SelectedItem.Value;
    RadGrid1.DataSource = GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM [Products] WHERE ([ProductID] = @PhoneID)");
}

private static DataTable GetDataTable(string queryString)
{
    SqlConnection MySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter MySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    MySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, MySqlConnection);

    DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
    MySqlConnection.Open();
    try
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
    }
    finally
    {
        MySqlConnection.Close();
    }

    return myDataTable;
}
```

Any Idea where i can mention the ProductID for Select Parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but are you looking simply to put your phoneId into your query string like this?

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
        {
            string PhoneID = RadComboBox1.SelectedItem.Value;
            RadGrid1.DataSource = GetDataTable(string.Format("SELECT * FROM [Products] WHERE ([ProductID] = {0})", PhoneID));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, it solved my problem :)  ..... the only issue i am having now is with RadGrid Refresh .... the grid is not updating unless i refresh .. already tried Postback in page load

Answer (score 0):

`RadGrid1.DataBind();     <===== INSERT THIS AFTER RadGrid1.DataSource line`

Comment: Calling DataBind in the RadGrid1_NeedDataSource will throw an exception.